# Using Site.Master function from WebForms in asp.NET MVC 5

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, webforms, master-pages

I have old project written in WebForms. Now I wan to add new module (using MVC 5) to existing project but with existing Site.Master (in WebForms).

I've added everything accoring tutorial and almost everything works: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MixingRazorViewsAndWebFormsMasterPagesWithASPNETMVC3.aspx and http://www.eworldui.net/blog/post/2011/01/07/Using-Razor-Pages-with-WebForms-Master-Pages.aspx

I have just one problem: when I'm in MVC page and I click on menu item (it's in Site.Master with action onclick="Logout()) it run "index" from current controller (ex. Home/Index or Home/About) and just refresh current page.

I want to use Site.Master in both places (WebForms and MVC 5) and when I click on Site.Master element I want to use functions from code behind.

Do you have any ideas or tips how to solve it?

Comment: WinForms does not equal WebForms.

Comment: You can't do that.  The whole point of MVC is to abandon the codebehind pattern.

Comment: @LarsTech: you're right - I mean WebForms :)

Comment: @SLaks: I know it, but I need to use old Site.Master with new module - I think that it's possible, but I don't know where to start.

Comment: @Tomasz Too much work, you might as well just rewrite Site.Master as a _Layout.cshtml file